# How can I make an arbitrary Emacs buffer "hidden"?

Tags: emacs

Several emacs extensions create "junk" buffers, and I have to manually remove them from various buffer lists.

Emacs has a concept of "hidden buffers", which is used for instance for the minibuffer.

How can I make an arbitrary buffer a hidden buffer?

Comment: @Ahmed Right place to ask, just really poorly written.

Comment: @Trey Jackson Why? I thought it was pretty clear

Comment: It's unclear what you consider to be junk buffers and why you need/want to remove them from lists.  In other words, you describe a problem (w/out much detail) and then propose a solution, and ask how to implement the solution.  That's why I consider it poorly written - you have two questions.  1) to fix the problem you want fixed, 2) how to make arbitrary buffers hidden.

Comment: @TreyJackson: I think it's reasonable to assume that sabof knows which buffers he wants to make hidden, although he should specify if he wants to refer to them by name... Or to use some sort of trigger or hook to determine which one he wants to hide automatically.

Comment: @Arafangion obviously he knows which buffers to remove b/c he removes them manually.  The point is there are two questions here, making the buffers "hidden" may not solve his first problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Emacs does have a concept of uninteresting/hidden buffers - and designates them as such by making their names begin with a space.  See the documentation for [buffer names](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Names.html).  You can make a buffer "uninteresting" by changing its name to begin with a space.

Try <kbd>M-x make-buffer-uninteresting</kbd>:

```
(defun make-buffer-uninteresting ()
  "rename the current buffer to begin with a space"
  (interactive)
  (unless (string-match-p "^ " (buffer-name))
    (rename-buffer (concat " " (buffer-name)))))
```

Comment: One question: if you rename a buffer like this, how will the original extension know that you changed it. Or, equivalently, is there some easy way of hiding a buffer without confusing whatever extension is using it?

Comment: Presumably it will keep a reference to the buffer object somewhere, and will find it this way.
Since the name changes if you open a second buffer that would have been named identically, the practice should be quite common

Comment: @Tikhon - that's why I was saying the question was poorly written, this routine could break the extensions (whatever they are) if they're looking for buffers by name.  If they keep track of the buffers by value, they're ok b/c only the name changed...

Answer (score 4):

If you enable `ido` (which you should because i don't know why you would use emacs without it), then you can configured which buffers are ignored using the `ido-ignore-buffers` list, which is a list of regex's specifying buffers to ignore for normal buffer switching.  (really, you should be using ido if you aren't already).